# Spring xml initializes beans when declared in child class but if the same is declared in parent class bean initialization fails

Tags: spring, unitils

There are lot of Unitils based integration test classes in my application which uses `@SpringApplicationContext` (with different spring xmls from different modules) . In order to reduce the number of spring contexts being created, we planned to create a base test class and initialize the spring contexts only from this base class and make all the other tests to extend this base class.

base class:

> com.org.module1.mypack;
>
> > @SpringApplicationContext({ "spring-module1.xml", "spring-module2.xml", "spring-    module3.xml" })
> >     public abstract class BaseTest{
> >         ...
> >         }

child class before change:

> com.org.module1.mypack.performance;
>
> > @SpringApplicationContext({ "spring-module4.xml" })
> >     public class ChildTest extends BaseTest{
> >         ..
> >         }

base class after change:

> com.org.module1.mypack;
>
> > @SpringApplicationContext({ "spring-module1.xml", "spring-module2.xml", "spring-        module3.xml", "spring-module4.xml" })
> >     public abstract class BaseTest{
> >         ...
> >         }

child class after change:

> com.org.module1.mypack.performance;
>
> > //@SpringApplicationContext({ "spring-module4.xml" })
> >     public class ChildTest extends BaseTest{
> >         ..
> >         }

Now I get below error message and my context is not created:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.org.module5.prepare.MyBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myBean)}`

When the spring-module4.xml was in the child class, the context was created normally and all the tests executed as usual.

Note: all the spring xml files are in src/main/resources, except spring-module4.xml is in src/test/resources

Comment: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` clearly exlpains that the parent class has no visibility of MyBean. Does that ring any bell for anybody?

Answer (score 0):

By default annotations on classes are not inherited, unless they have @Inherited in their definition.

Comment: That means you have to put @SpringApplicationContext on the child as well. But following the documentation: http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html, you can keep your new configuration as you have it.

Comment: I tried adding `@SpringApplicationContext` to the child class as well... but still getting the same errors